# Telerik Gridview Hierarchical data

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik, radgridview

I have a gridview which contains Test Informations. I want to see the lower of group tests in radgridview but I couldn't. I have tried the solutions which are stated in the Internet. I am about to go crazy. I didn't defined a initial datasource. I assigned it in form_load because I am filtering data by some parameters. After assigned the datasources, I defined relation between two templates. I entered parent and child column name and selected master template and child template but it doesn't work. When I press + button all of tests are seen

```
        GridViewTemplate firstChildtemplate = new GridViewTemplate();
        firstChildtemplate.DataSource = dtblLowSampleTestResult;//It's a datatable which contains the lower tests
        gridWorkingList.MasterTemplate.Templates.Add(firstChildtemplate);

        GridViewRelation relation = new GridViewRelation(gridWorkingList.MasterTemplate,firstChildtemplate);
        relation.ChildTemplate = firstChildtemplate;
        relation.RelationName = "LowerTests";
        relation.ParentColumnNames.Add("sample_test_result_id");
        relation.ChildColumnNames.Add("low_samp_test_res_rid");

        gridWorkingList.Relations.Add(relation);
```

Comment: Please post some code as it will be easier for some to understand.

Comment: I have solved this. radGridView doesn't support Hierarchal Data without datasource. So If you add rows manually, Hierarchal data won't work.